# sum 2 lists and get 3rd in f#, please correct my syntax

Tags: .net, f#

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
7 2 3 5
10 12 20

res = 10 + max(7,2) ; 12 + max(2,3); 20 + max(3,5)
```

this is my code so far:

```
//prevline.count is always currLine.count+1

let getResLine currLine prevLine =
   let rec loop resLine prevLine' = function
       |[] -> resLine
       |hd::tl -> loop (hd + (max (List.nth prevLine' 0) (List.nth prevLine' 1)))::resLine (List.tail prevLine') tl
   loop [] prevLine currLine
```

but it doesn't compile, it tells me some type mismatch errors, probably somebody more experienced could see some obvious errors that I made, please help

**Edit:** updated my code accoding to the suggestions, but it's still not working

Comment: You can't use `::` to concatenate a list with a single item, it has to be the other way around.

Comment: @svick I had to put `( )` around first argument `::` is fine

Comment: Right, sorry, I got confused.

Comment: An aside which may not be obvious for someone coming here who is new to F#: the function body needs indenting.

Comment: I was showing some fellow developers recursive code the other day and realized I couldn't remember how to write it.  Why?  Because I found that writing folds accomplished the same thing and was a lot less error-prone.  I understand you're trying to figure out why _your_ code isn't working but ultimately you'll be better off approaching problems of this sort with higher-order functions and map/fold/reduce types of approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want to split a list into a head and a tail, use just `hd::tl` (without brackets).

Second, you don't seem to be actually creating the result list. And I think you don't need an accumulator here.

Third, I think it's confusing to use the same variable names in both functions (because you can use the variables from the outer function in the inner function).

Because of all that, I would rewrite your function like this:

```
let getResLine prevLine resLine =
    let rec loop prevLine' = function
        |[] -> []
        |hd::tl -> (hd + (max (List.nth prevLine' 0) (List.nth prevLine' 1)))::loop (List.tail prevLine') tl
    loop prevLine resLine
```

Although I think it would be more readable using higher-order functions, not explicit recursion:

```
let getResLine prevLine resLine =
    let maxes line = Seq.map2 (max) prevLine (List.tail prevLine)
    Seq.map2 (+) (maxes prevLine) resLine | Seq.toList
```

I used `Seq.map2`, insted of `List.map2`, because the latter doesn't handle lists of unequal length.

Comment: sorry, I've edited my question, first version was too wrong, parameters for getResLine are prevLine and currentLine and the result is resLine, and I would like to use accumulators because they are much more efficient

Comment: @ChuckNorris, why do you think accumulators are more efficient? Especially since it would probably mean you have to reverse the result list in the end?

Comment: @ChuckNorris, and if you want to use accumulator, you actually need to use it: your second case doesn't contain `resLine` anywhere.

Comment: I updated my question, now I'm using the accumulator in the second case, but I get a compile error, could you please take a look

Comment: so is this a case when accumulators don't make sense ? cuz usually they do, that's why they exist

Comment: Yes, I think they don't make sense here. They certainly have their uses and it's good to know about them, but I think you should first try to write your functions without them and use them only when it makes sense. Or avoid the issue completely and use higher-order functions.

Answer (score 9):

By the way, you might be interested in another way of looking at the problem. Start with the list of numbers:

```
let nums1 = [7; 2; 3; 5]
let nums2 = [10; 12; 20]
```

Then

```
let res = nums1 
          |> Seq.pairwise 
          |> Seq.map2 (fun a (b1, b2) -> a + max b1 b2) nums2
```

This has the benefit of being more semantically matched to what you want to do.

**Edit:** Simplified using `map2` instead of `zip` and `map` thanks to @Daniel and @JonHarrop.

Comment: nice, after I learn all these functions, I'll be able to understand this code

Comment: Just run them individually against the functions in FSI and see the output. Very straightforward.

Comment: @ChuckNorris I can follow yamen's code better than I can follow your question.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci yes it's very good compact code +1, but I wanted to find the errors that I made

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea what your question is asking but yamen's answer can be simplified to:

```
let res =
  Seq.pairwise nums1
  |> Seq.map2 (fun a (b1, b2) -> a + max b1 b2) nums2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want

```
let getResLine currLine prevLine =
    let rec loop resLine prevLine = function
        |[] -> resLine
        |hd::tl -> loop (hd + max (List.nth prevLine 0) (List.nth prevLine 1)) (List.tail prevLine) tl
    loop 0 prevLine currLine
```

Comment: @ChuckNorris - you should have `hd::t1` instead of `[hd::t1]` as well